# Android 5 - Spinner dropdown list over the navigation bar

Tags: android, spinner, android-5.0-lollipop

I've a problem with Android programming :/ 
I've created a layout programmatically, but the dropdown lists of the spinners don't work as aspected... As you can see [here](http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a247/prgpascal/IMG-20150512-WA0001_zpskubelhqz.jpg), they cover the navigation bar on the bottom.

This appens ONLY on Android 5 (API level 21) and above. 
I've tested this on Android 4.XX and it works well.

Could this be an Android bug?

Thank you :)

PS: Here is a part of my code:

```
   //--- SPINNER ---
        spinnersArray[j] = new Spinner(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        spinnersArray[j].setId(j+100); //set a different ID

        //Create the Array that will populate the Spinner, than shuffle it
        Character[] tmpArray = new Character[1 + plaintextCharsArray.length]; 
        tmpArray[0] = ciphertextCharsArray[j]; //first char is a symbol
        Character[] shuffledPlainTextCharsArray = MyUtils.shuffleArray(plaintextCharsArray.clone()); //shuffle a copy of plaintextCharsArray
        for (int i=0; i<plaintextCharsArray.length; i++){
            tmpArray[i+1] = shuffledPlainTextCharsArray[i];
        }

        //Spinner ArrayAdapter 
        final ArrayAdapter<Character> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Character>(
                parentActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                R.layout.game_controller_fragment_spinner, 
                tmpArray){

                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(font);   //Set the FONT

                    return v;
                }

                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(font);   //Set the FONT
                    return v;
                }
        };

        //Set the style and the adapter
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.game_controller_fragment_spinner_dropdown);
        spinnersArray[j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apptheme_spinner_background_holo_light);
        spinnersArray[j].setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        //Find and set the current Spinner selected item
        int h = 0; boolean found = false;
        while ((!found) && (h<tmpArray.length)){
            if (gameArray[j] == tmpArray[h]){
                spinnersArray[j].setSelection(h); //set the Spinner selected item
                found = true;
            }
            h++;
        }

        //Spinner item listener
        spinnersArray[j].setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyItemSelectedListener(tmpArray, j));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue can be two fold, although I haven't done this programmatically.  I have run into this a bunch of times.

1)  Ensure that your z value `android:elevation=` is correct.

2)  Many times it's the order that it is defined, whether in an actual xml layout or the equivalent programmatically, and in what type of Layout it is contained in.  I my experience it has been the items that are defined later that take preference when it comes to the z or elevation.